Run Google App Scripts client side to import image in intranet link in GSheets
I have a local link: image.domain.loc/image01 that contains an image,
There is any way to access this image in GSheet /GAPPS script without a Proxy or a tunnel?
I need an easy way to insert image in bulk in my GSHEET
If not possible, any idea with tampermonkey and js?
I tried to create an html page, but I don't know how to proceed to insert the images into the sheet

You can show the html page in the side bar. Look into google.script.run

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
